# Installing aws-sdk-php in local machine -- http request failed

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to install aws-sdk-php in my local machine using [this reference url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/installation.html)

When I try -- `php composer.phar require aws/aws-sdk-php`

It gives me the following error:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   The
>   "http://packagist.org/p/aws/aws-sdk-php%24a8b264f89dd462e84ffdc6487d616b6126bbc20d00351e8a9daf81c5d66f2305.json"
>   file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed!
>
> require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress]
>   [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev]
>   [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies]
>   [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest]
>   [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
>   [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] []...

Any help/hint is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
php -r "file_get_contents('http://packagist.org/p/aws/aws-sdk-php%24a8b264f89dd462e84ffdc6487d616b6126bbc20d00351e8a9daf81c5d66f2305.json');"
```

try this way

OR

hit this: `composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org`

and try YOUR way again

Comment: It does not install the latest stable version of the SDK.

Comment: hit this: `composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org` and try YOUR way again